# How to access FB share in BB10?

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I have tried to share on facebook But was not able to share anything.
The code that i have used is:-

In Javascript

```
FB.init({
         appId: 'some id', 
         cookie: true,
            status:true, 
            xfbml:true,
            oauth:true
         });


      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'http://www.example.com',
          picture: imageToShare,
          name: 'name',
          caption: 'This Link is Shared through the some application.',
          description: ''

        };

        function callback(response) {
          //document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }
```

In config file

```
<access uri="http://connect.facebook.net" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is share something from your app to Facebook you can do this quite easily using Cards.

I wrote a blog post on this here: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/02/twitter-and-facebook-cards/

Basically, you're using the BlackBerry invocation framework to invoke the Card, and passing some data to that card.

```
function invokeFacebook() {
    blackberry.invoke.invoke({
        target: "Facebook",
        action: "bb.action.SHARE",
        type: "text/plain",
        data: "I’m eating tacos with Alex."
    }, onSuccess, onError);
}
```

If you want to share an image you would just swap out the 'data' attribute with:

```
uri: 'file://' + pathToFile,
```

There's also a sample app on our GitHub repo: https://github.com/ctetreault/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/invoke/invoker

Comment: Hi chadtatro,
I am getting an error "invocation error : INVOKE_NO_TARGET_ERROR" Can u please help me out ?
Thanks